# PHP contact form script is not adding custom fields to the email

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I have a template and I wanted to add some custom fields to the PHP code that would be sent back as an email. I have added the variables and included those variables in the email configuration, but they are not appearing in the actual email, just the original variables. Here is my code

**HTML**

```html
<form method="post" action="php/contact-form.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
  <fieldset>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name*" />
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Your Email*" />
    <input name="ether" type="text" id="ether" placeholder="Ethereum Address*" />
    <input name="qty" id="qty" type="text" placeholder="Amount of DDtokens*" />
    <input name="price" id="price" type="hidden" value="0.00051" />
    <input readonly name="total" id="total" type="text" placeholder="Value in Ether" />
    <label class="field-label"> Select Country </label>
    <label class="field select telSelect">
         <select id="address-country"> </select>
         <i class="arrow double"></i>                    
         </label>

    <label class="field-label"> Telephone Number </label>
    <label class="field">
         <input type="tel" id="phone9" name="phone9" class="gui-input">
                                                    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" placeholder="Your Message*"></textarea>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" data-ao-show-popup="banner16" class="submit" id="submit" value="Request Tokens" />

</form>
```

**PHP**

```
// CHANGE EMAIL ADDRESS ON LINE 45.


if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email']; 
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$verify   = $_POST['verify'];
$ether    = $_POST['ether'];
$qty      = $_POST['qty'];
$total    = $_POST['total'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.

//$address = "example@example.com";
$address = "info@ddtoken.io";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name, their additional message is as follows. They have requested $qty DDTokens valued at $total. Their Ethereum Address is $ether. " . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply . $ether . $qty . $total, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h4 class='highlight'>Thank you for your requested DDTokens <strong>$name</strong>, your request has been submitted to us and will be finalized within 7 days after performing KYC functions.  You will receive a confirmation email after your transaction has closed and thank you for your interest in DDTokens.</h4>";
    echo '<a href="index.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Home</a>';    
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}



?>
```

```js
/* -------------------
    Contact form
    ---------------------*/
$('#contactform').submit(function() {
  var action = $(this).attr('action');
  $("#message").slideUp(250, function() {
    $('#message').hide();
    $('#submit')
      .after('<img src="img/assets/contact-form-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
      .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $.post(action, {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        etherAddress: $('#etherAddress').val(),
        qty: $('#qty').val(),
        total: $('#total').val(),
        ether: $('#ether').val(),

        comments: $('#comments').val(),

      },
      function(data) {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
        $('#message').slideDown(250);
        $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
          $(this).remove();
        });
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        if (data.match('success') !== null) $('#contactform').slideUp(850, 'easeInOutExpo');
      }
    );
  });
  return false;
});
```

I have defined the variables and set their ID's to the vaiiable names in the form and the method is set to post. How do I return the values of the custom fields I created for the form?

Comment: Which fields do you want to send in email?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$_REQUEST` in your .php to get the variables:

```
$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
```

Comment: your "POST" In the HTML is taking that info and sending it to the PHP.. but the PHP has to "REQUEST" it.    It's basically erasing what your HTML sent to it.

Comment: This is very very wrong and bad information. You need to go through the basic php tutorials. FYI using `$_REQUEST` has major security vulnerabilities

Comment: why not use $_GET? as originally suggested?

Comment: @akintude I don't know PHP or JS very well, but where would I need to declare these so they get passed through to the receiving email? I have just updated the post with the javascript part of the form

Comment: @Bradley Carter From what I have gathered, $_GET is only good for nonsensitive data and is displayed on the webpage, $_POST is better for sensitive data. I think my problem is the new variables are not getting picked up